# is it possible to play a sound file onclick depends on url?

Tags: javascript, html, audio

Is it possible to play a sound file onclick depends on url?

example:
url/sample/#1

onclick play sound1

url/sample/#3

onclick play sound2

Answer (score 0):

why dont you use the html5 data- property they seem much neater
the html

```
<ul id="audiolist">
<li data-audiourl="url_of_audio_file_1">sound 1</li>
<li data-audiourl = "url_of_audio_file_2">sound 2</li>          
</ul>
```

and the javascript

```
<script type="text/javascript">

  $(function() {
      $("#audiolist li").on("click", function() {
          $("#audio").attr({
              "src": $(this).attr("data-audiourl"),
"autoplay": "autoplay"

          })
      })
      $("#audio").attr({
          "src": $("#audiolist li").eq(0).attr("data-audiourl")
      })
  })
</script>
```

but if you want for url you can modify the code for anchor tags instead of lists